# Validate an integer input value in SpreadSheet with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to validate an integer input value in SpreadSheet with GAS.

However, the SpreadSheet validator is not very powerful, with no regular expressions.

Is there any better way to do this?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet?#datavalidationbuilder

Comment: You could use DataValidation Custom Formula `=A1=FLOOR(A1)`

Comment: Custom Fomula was also considered, but was abandoned due to the need to make the cell location variable for generalization. In this example, we want to make "A1" a variable.

Comment: Let say you set the DatValidition to A1 as custom formula.  If you expand the range to cover a column A1:A10 for example, the formula will also expand the range.

Comment: Thank you." I don't understand the GAS code to "expand the range". If you could tell me where I can find some sample code, I would appreciate it.

Comment: "Expand the range", not really sure if you meant dragging the bottom-right corner of the cell once the formula is applied to the first one, or actually adding the range to the formula. For those looking for the later, following @TheWizEd example, it would be `=A1:A10=FLOOR(A1:A10)`. I used it not for data validation but for cell formatting.

Comment: @maganap, that is not what I meant.  I create the data validation formula `=A=FLOOR(A1)` for cell A1.  Then in the Data Validation dialog I expand the range from `A1` to `A1:A10`.  Data Validition will automatically adjust the Data Validation formula for cell A2 as `=A2=FLOOR(A2)`

Answer (score 2):

There is no GAS script.  You simply create the custom formula for one cell say A1 and then expand the range in the Data Validation sidebar as shown below.  I expanded to A1:A10.

[image]